# MYSQL: Copying a table from a snapshot into production

Tags: mysql, backup, snapshot

i have a snapshot of the database that I took before i did some data migration. The data migration messed up, so I want to retrieve the data from the snapshot to migrate over to the production database.

Question: How do i access the snapshot, and how do i retrieve the available data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anyone can answer your question, you need to specify:

1) How did you take your snapshot.  ie, what form is it in, .sql or raw binary; what is the filename, etc.

2) what version of mysql are you running?

Given that you have a text file dump of the database, and you want to retrieve a subset of it, you may want to load up the snapshot into another database (preferably on another machine), and export only the data of interest.  Then you can import that into your production database, using any number of tools, such as the mysql command line, or MySqlAdministrator.

for more information, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/backup-and-recovery.html

(change the 5.5 to the version of your particular installation for more exact instructions, if necessary)